# UIPickerView Behaving Erratically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

So I feel stupid asking about this, but I simply cannot figure out what is going wrong. Basically, when I click a textField that has a UIPickerView as its `inputView` it will show up very quickly and then disappear. However, the toolBar (its `accessoryView` still remains on screen). I haven't seen anyone else online who has experienced this, so that's why I had to ask it on SO.

At first I thought it had something do with when I was setting the pickerView's `.isHidden` property. But I omitted those calls to no effect.

Thus, I will be including all of the code related to my pickerViews since I really don't know where the issue is. I'm sure it's something minor I'm missing, but any help would be appreciated.

```
class myAssessmentsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var contentSelectionTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var contentOrderingTextField: UITextField!

var contentSelectionPickerView: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
var contentOrderingPickerView: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

var contentSelectionOptions: [String] = ["All", "Physics HL", "Chemistry HL", "Spanish Ab SL"]
var contentOrderingOptions: [String] = ["Date", "Subject", "Grade", "Title"]

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    contentSelectionPickerView.tag = 1 //for the delegate methods
    contentSelectionPickerView.isHidden = true //commenting this out did nothing
    contentSelectionPickerView.delegate = self
    contentSelectionPickerView.dataSource = self

    contentSelectionTextField.inputView = contentSelectionPickerView //set pickerView as responder
    contentSelectionTextField.delegate = self

    contentOrderingPickerView.tag = 2 //for the delegate methods
    contentOrderingPickerView.isHidden = true //commenting this out also did nothing
    contentOrderingPickerView.delegate = self
    contentOrderingPickerView.dataSource = self

    initializePickerViewToolBar(clearButtonFunc: "clearPressedContentSelectionPickerView", doneButtonFunc: "donePressedContentSelectionPickerView", textField: contentSelectionTextField)
    initializePickerViewToolBar(clearButtonFunc: "clearPressedContentOrderingPickerView", doneButtonFunc: "donePressedContentOrderingPickerView", textField: contentOrderingTextField)

    contentOrderingTextField.inputView = contentOrderingPickerView //set pickerView as responder
    contentOrderingTextField.delegate = self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1 //same for both pickers
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView.tag == 1 { //contentSelectionPickerView
        return contentSelectionOptions.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 { //contentOrderingPickerView
        return contentOrderingOptions.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    if pickerView.tag == 1 { //contentSelectionPickerView
        return contentSelectionOptions[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 { //contentOrderingPickerView
        return contentOrderingOptions[row]
    } else {
        return "1"
    }

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        contentSelectionTextField.text = contentSelectionOptions[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        contentOrderingTextField.text = contentOrderingOptions[row]
    }

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField == contentSelectionTextField {
        contentSelectionPickerView.isHidden = false //also was not source of problem
    } else if textField == contentOrderingTextField {
        contentOrderingPickerView.isHidden = false //same here
    }

}

func donePressedContentSelectionPickerView(){
    contentSelectionTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
func donePressedContentOrderingPickerView(){
    contentOrderingTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func clearPressedContentSelectionPickerView(){
    contentSelectionTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    contentSelectionTextField.text = ""
}
func clearPressedContentOrderingPickerView(){
    contentOrderingTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    contentOrderingTextField.text = ""
}

func initializePickerViewToolBar(clearButtonFunc: String, doneButtonFunc: String, textField: UITextField){

    let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height/6, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: 40.0))
    toolBar.layer.position = CGPoint(x: textField.frame.size.width/2, y: textField.frame.size.height-20.0)
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.black

    let clearButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector(clearButtonFunc))
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: Selector(doneButtonFunc))
    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

    toolBar.setItems([clearButton,flexSpace,doneButton], animated: true)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}

}
```

Here is also a photo of what I am talking about visually. As you can see at the bottom of the screen the accessoryView is still visible but the content isn't. I would think that the accessoryView would be a subview of the UIPickerView and that they would disappear together but that is apparently not the case.

[image: The issue]

Again, apologies for all of the code (and the large image), I know it is a lot to read through, but any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is this line in your titleForRow? self.view.endEditing(true)

Comment: @MikeTaverne Wow I don't know why I didn't investigate that further when  I saw it. That was totally it thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that one of the answers from SO that I was following told me to include `self.view.endEditing(true)` in my pickerViewTitleForRow delegate method. This meant whenever the titles were being set, the first responder was being dismissed, causing this issue. Removing it caused the problem to disappear. Thanks to @MikeTaverne for pointing it out.